# UK - Is my contract collectively bargained or a personal contract?

Tags: salary, united-kingdom, unions

I genuinely like my job and I can see growth in it. I do my normal engineering stuff and also build cases for projects that cost millions of pounds, it looks as if I am going to be moved into managing them, and I have convinced a number of important people than I can anticipate important technical problems that other people see. There are a few big projects at work based on cost and return on investment which I was the prime mover for. I don't want to leave when I have so many babies at my current place of work.

Despite that, my employer has a new policy of deliberately underpaying staff and I can make 50% more working (literally) next door doing another technical job with far fewer responsibilities. I have signed my new contract and informally told my manager that I intend to leave but that I'd really prefer not to, so he has worked fairly hard to find out if there is any flexibility on salary, only to be told there definitely isn't. I did have a meeting with our Chief Engineer where I complained about salary, he said he was not in control of salaries but he did agree to find  way to get my recent promotion back paid for a year, so I think I am "valued" by people but not "valued" the company.

My employer is highly unionised and we have collective bargaining arrangements. My employer succeeded in paying people less by issuing contracts to new employees before they can be represented by the union, but these new contracts say all negotiations are "collectively bargained". The payscales on these new contracts apparently "Must" be negotiated with the unions, but for whatever reason in 3 years no negotiations have happened so there is only the entry level salary for each grade.

In my possibly Quixotic attempts to continue working for an employer that clearly hates me, I have tried to find a way to negotiate my salary, and my salary alone. Whether this is by being promoted in post or some other mechanism. My employer said it won't do this because my contract is collectively bargained with the union, and therefore if I don't like my pay then I should complain to the union.

I phoned my union's (Prospect) Head Office, and the person I spoke to on the phone said my contract was actually a "personal contract" because it was written without union consultation, and therefore is not and will never be a "collectively bargained" contract in the most literal and formal sense of the word. This meant my company reps have an obligation to try and crowbar my employer into sitting around a table with them to discuss my salary, and my salary alone.

The Head Office people forwarded my case onto the local reps who I spoke to on the phone and filled out a case form for. Over the phone they said they had never heard of "personal contracts" and understood these are very special cases for executives. They also said they will not let me get a promotion in post, because if they let me have one then everyone should get one.

Since then (one week) I haven't heard from the local reps and they put the phone down on me when I ring. I'll quickly point out that our conversation was perfectly polite and I was not hostile in any way, so I don't understand the lack of communication.

Have I got the wrong end of the stick from Head Office here? Should I be persistent with local reps or am I just banging my head against a brick wall?

Comment: If you can make 50% more by literally working next door, then get a job next door.

Comment: In that job I'm just going to sit around and wait for stuff to break, then if the electricians can't fix it then I go in and fix it. I feel like I don't want to go back to doing that unless I really, really have to.

Comment: Why would you care? The point is you won't get anything. Whatever excuse given by your employer is not relevant, the simple fact they're not coming with an other offer is a red flag. You will never get threated correctly there, just run...

Comment: If you want more money take it by going next door, if not accept what you have, your choice but choose.

Comment: Collective bargaining **should** be easy, and it affects all employees (but only union members get to vote on the deal). If your union is saying that they don't do collective bargaining with your employer, but your employer will only deal with them, then you're stuffed. Looks like you need an employment lawyer. Your union should be able to help with that: that's what you pay your subs for. However it may be that you're actually in dispute with your union as well as your employer. Not a good place to be.

Comment: There are enough clues in your posts on this subject that I'm now fairly confident of the identity of your employer.  If I've got the identification right, the chief executive made a press statement in June 2016, suggesting that one reason for implementing the 'new contract' with worse pay and conditions was that the previous package was so good that it was causing recruitment and retention problems for local public services.  If the company is trying to solve unrelated organizations' recruitment and retention problems, negotiating with them wil be a bizarre experience, for you and the union.

Comment: I wondered if somebody would figure it out. They paid a big 4 firm to calculate national"average" salaries but it's not right. I actively resent being drawn here using a well-funded recruitment campaign and a decent headline starting salary only for progression to grind to a literal halt after that. We were promised our new contracts would still pay us well and be negotiated soon, but in that time my university friends are making £20k more than I am for similar if not less responsible jobs. Nothing here is very safe and if they want to drive people out then it's only going to be less safe.

Comment: Yes, given that safety _is_ their core business, you'd think they'd be a bit better at it.

Comment: Company culture is that engineering is for sitting about and waiting for things to break. Asset management and long term planning are a joke here. Every physical job is planned to the nth degree around safety but the assets themselves are horrendously mismanaged and often unsafely degraded. Rant over.

Comment: 'Asset management and long term planning are a joke here.'... which I guess neatly brings us back to my answer to your other very recent question, where I mentioned the competences that are in the UK-SPEC C.Eng. standard, but not in the UK-SPEC Eng.Tech. standard.  One of them is 'Define a holistic and systematic approach to risk identification, assessment and management'.

Comment: I upvoted both Fattie and Gnasher - go and work next door; it's not like you have to change city to get a (large) payrise. Also, +1 for your use of the word _Quixotic_.

Answer (score 7):

> Is my contract collectively bargained or a personal contract?

It's an ordinary job contract and has no connection, at all, to the Unions, in any way.

It is completely, utterly, unrelated to the unions in any way.

(There may be some confusion about the Union-related term of art "personal contract" - which has simply utterly no connection to the issue under discussion here.)

> I don't understand the lack of communication.... (from the Union)

They would be completely confused by you talking to them about the contract in question - which has absolutely no connection to the Union in any way.

Good luck in your new job.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but my union does have an obligation to negotiate on behalf of people on personal contracts if they ask for it, which I have in writing and verbally ove rthe phone. so from my understanding my local reps should at least make it look as if they made an effort? I realise moving on is probably the best move, but I'm keen to try and fully understand this contract situation.

Comment: hi @rvukwdvypd - you may be right; I can only offer you my opinion.  In my opinion / understanding, you guys have a big mixup over the term "personal contract".  They're referring to a very specific thing that has utterly no connection, in any way, at all, whatsoever, to what you're talking about.  Regarding what you are talking about, it just has nothing at all in any way to do with the Union - it would be like if you called, say, the Police, or Tescos, about the issue.  they'd just be like "huh, what?"  :)   I can only give you my understanding.  Cheers!

Comment: I'll upvote this answer, because I guess it's true and helpful, but I'm afraid I won't put it down as "the answer" because it hasn't settled the answer of whether or not my current contract is "collectively bargained" or a "personal" contract in my mind.